# Export Rails model validations to hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, validation

I'm looking for engine which export rails model validations to hash/json for me. I found gem client-side-validations, but this is complex solution, I just need export validations to frontend in json.

```
validates :name, length: ...., presence: true  
  to
{name: {length: ..., presence: true}}
```

Any suggests? Thanks...

Comment: Hello, It's been a while, but I am interested if you achieved your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could overwrite the `validates` function to do what you want?